# Gitlab Maven Package Registry. Install a package with artifact dependency

Tags: java, maven, gitlab

I need to connect Package Registry in Gitlab using Maven Repository. I did everything according to: https://gitlab.com/help/user/packages/maven_repository/index.md. I have a problem with "Installing a package".

I have added dependency in my pom.xml and then tried to mvn install. But I have an error. As far as I know, Maven should use the repository from pom.xml to search for my artifact, but it doesn't

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.479 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-28T20:23:59+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin '.upprpo:budget-planner_' from the repositories [local (C:\Users\User\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.version.PluginVersionResolutionException: Error resolving version for plugin '.upprpo:budget-planner_' from the repositories [local (C:\Users\User\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository
at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver.selectVersion (DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java:236)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver.resolveFromRepository (DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java:146)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java:94)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.resolvePluginVersion (MojoDescriptorCreator.java:281)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor (MojoDescriptorCreator.java:236)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments (DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:104)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments (DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:89)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginVersionResolutionException
PS D:\JavaLabs\budget-planner gitlab> mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=nsu.upprpo:budget-planner_:2.0
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] 'dependencies.dependency[nsu.upprpo:budget-planner_:2.0]' for nsu.upprpo:budget-planner_:2.0 is referencing itself. @ line 158, column 21
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project nsu.upprpo:budget-planner_:2.0 (D:\JavaLabs\budget-planner gitlab\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency[nsu.upprpo:budget-planner_:2.0]' for nsu.upprpo:budget-planner_:2.0 is referencing itself. @ line 158, column 21
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

And there is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>nsu.upprpo</groupId>
<artifactId>budget-planner_</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <sonar.host.url>http://84.237.50.237:9000/</sonar.host.url>
    <sonar.login>9508b619882a5709e02a1902a6361249c8e65db6</sonar.login>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
    <sonar.coverage.exclusions>**/gui/*, **/application/*</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
            <executions>

                <execution>
                    <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/19026178/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/19026178/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>

    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/19026178/packages/maven</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.14.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
        <artifactId>forms_rt</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdatepicker</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdatepicker</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>nsu.upprpo</groupId>
        <artifactId>budget-planner_</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I found information that I should use Artifactory or something similar, but I would like to do without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the plugin '.upprpo:budget-planner_' something you are building?  If so you'll need to build it and put it in the projects' repository first.  I appear that your project is still looking for that dependency on `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2`.

If that's an *external* dependency you're not building, check the spelling of the name and if it is in the main Maven repository.